# How to render an animation of a scene in right viewpoint mode? i.e. so it appears in "2D" and from the right side

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, 3d-view

Complete beginner here. I have an animated sequence of some rotating cylinder objects and want to render this sequence and save it as a video.
[image: Red circle is intended output]
I thought that the view on the left of the screen represents what the rendered animation will look like. I have in "right view" mode in the viewpoint settings because that is the angle I want to record (first picture). However, the render looks different to what I expected (second picture).

Also, I'm unsure why there's purple light on the objects when they only have a grey or black material on them and there is no additional lighting in the scene (only the default light). The image below is what the final render looks like.

[image: Unexpected output - wrong angle and strange colour/lighting]

Was trying to attach a .blend but couldn't work out how to.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendered result will always be the camera view which you can access by clicking 0 on the numpad or View > cameras > Active camera.

If you want the Camera's FOV to match with the left image, simply search for "align camera to view" in the search dialog. Since the left image is in ortographic view, you can change your camera to ortographic in the camera settings under lens > type > ortographic.

If something is purple, this usually means that an image texture is missing (renamed or moved to another folder, deleted etc.). Make sure that the cylinder materials have the correct image textures loaded. It could also be the case that you use an HDRi to light your scene which cannot be found.

You can share your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and following the instructions onscreen.